# Disabling the constant upgrade messages from subversion clients

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, subclipse, ankhsvn

Most everything about the subversion eco-system makes me happy; however the reminders to upgrade to newer versions of the tools gets annoying.  Is there any way to turn these off if I am rolling the client to hundreds of workstations?  I know I can dismiss the dialog box and tell it not to remind me but I want to never show the dialog boxes for Tortoise, subclipse, and Ankh.

Comment: Just update them.  More secure, perform better, more features, and the nagging goes away (until the next version anyway).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For AnkhSVN you can disable the automatic check using the registry.

```
HKCU\SOFTWARE\AnkhSVN\AnkhSVN\VisualStudio\<VERSION>\UpdateCheck
```

Where  is 8.0, 9.0 or 10.0

Create/set Interval to DWORD 0 to disable. This is the interval in hours.

Comment: I thought this would not be sufficient but after thinking it through it is of course the correct solution.  Another one of these check keys will not generated unless a newer version of ankh is installed.  Thanks so much.

Comment: Version is the Visual Studio version. You can also disable the check for updates for the current AnkhSVN version. Just check the "Don't show this again" box, and look what key is generated (it's in the same registry location, but called differently)

Answer (score 4):

I only use Tortoise, but to disable the upgrade messages you can just right click in explorer -> Settings -> Uncheck Automatically check for newer versions every week.

Did you look through the settings of Ankh and Subclipse to see if they have a similar option?